# How can I resolve this case of 'Useless use of a variable in a void context'?

Tags: perl, list, warnings

How can I resolve this case of 'Useless use of a variable in a void context'? (line 17)

```
sub next {
    my $page = shift;

    my $next_stage = $page->{tree}->{nextstage};
    my $prev_stage = $page->{stage};

    print "Moving from: $prev_stage to $next_stage.\n" if ($DEBUG);

    if ($next_stage eq "end") {
        serialize_grabber_conf_answers($page, $config_file_tmp);
        $grabber_initialized = 1;
        return FALSE;
    }

    unless (defined ($page->{next_page})) {
        serialize_grabber_conf_answers($page, $config_file_tmp);
        my $next_page = ($page, $config_file_tmp, $next_stage);
        $next_page->{stage} = $next_stage;
        $page->{next_page} = $next_page;
        $next_page->{prev_page} = $page;
    }

    return FALSE;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors), [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array?)

Comment: You have other problems. next_page does not look like it is a hash reference. Are you using 'strict'??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problematic line is

```
my $next_page = ($page, $config_file_tmp, $next_stage);
```

You are assigning to a scalar, so only the last member of the list will be used. The previous members are thrown away - useless use of a variable.